# How do I represent this JSON as C# classes?

Tags: c#

I'm struggling to represent this JSON as C# class structures (snipped for brevity):

```
{
  "subdomain_count": 1118434,
  "hostname": "google.com",
  "endpoint": "/v1/domain/google.com",
  "current_dns": {
    "txt": {
      "values": [
        {
          "value": "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all"
        },
        {
          "value": "MS=E4A68B9AB2BB9670BCE15412F62916164C0B20BB"
        }
      ],
      "first_seen": "2021-04-22"
    },
  },
  "apex_domain": "google.com",
  "alexa_rank": 1
}
```

I'm looking for help on how to represent this deeply-nested portion:

```
 "current_dns": {
    "txt": {
      "values": [
        {
          "value": "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all"
        },
```

I've tried various combinations like `List<List<string>>` and `Dictionary<Dictionary<List<string>, string>, string>` without any luck.

Comment: https://json2csharp.com/ or https://quicktype.io/csharp or let Visual Studio do it with paste as JSON.

Comment: Those are pretty great, but it helps to understand cause they won't always be right. For example, the first uses a class for `current_dns` instead of a dictionary, but a dictionary would make more sense. (The latter doesn't even work; it claims one of the keys is unquoted, which is nonsense.)

Comment: I've used both.  They both deserialize this JSON differently.  What I'm after is to learn how to do it myself.

Comment: The point is that these things are a good starting point. They give you 95% of the code, the rest you should figure out for yourself.

Comment: I agree. That's why I said "Those are pretty great".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not uniform. You have

- `.current_dns.txt.values` is an array
- `.current_dns.txt.first_seen` is a string.

So no generic dictionary/list combination will do.

---

- `{ "txt": ... }` is a JSON object. Those normally represent one of two things:

  - A dictionary (e.g. `Dictionary`)
  - A struct (e.g. `struct`, `class`)

  Without additional information about the JSON format, some guess work is needed here. Since `TXT` is one of many DNS record types, I presume `current_dns` is a collection of info grouped by DNS record type. As such, I think a `Dictionary` would work best here, but there's room for interpretation and preference.
- `{ "values": [ ... ], "first_seen": "2021-04-22" }` is also a JSON object. But this is clearly not a dictionary since the values have different types. (It's "not uniform".) We're going to have to build a `struct` or `class`.
- `[ ... ]` is a JSON array. `List` is the go-to choice for those.
- `{ "value": "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all" }` is yet another JSON object. It looks like it always has the singular key `value`, so we'll use a class for it.

This gets us the following:

```cs
public class DnsResultValue {
   public string value { get; set; }
}

public class DnsResult {
   public List<DnsResultValue> values     { get; set; }
   public string               first_seen { get; set; }
}

public Dictionary<string, DnsResult> current_dns { get; set; }
```

Comment: Not sure who's downvoting you here.  I understand how you came to the conclusion that no generic combination will work (thanks for explaining that).  Can you tell me how you determined to use the types you are using on these two classes?

Comment: Added. Changed one of my decisions in the process.

Comment: Thanks very much, @ikegami.  Your 2nd bullet there helps me tremendously; it's ultimately a root of something I had previously misunderstood.  Thanks for taking the time to elaborate on your answer!